# How to use Google Adsense with MVC C# Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, adsense

I am trying to add Google Adsense to my MVC mobile web application. I'd like to implement the Google Adsense Mobile content ad code. The Scripting Language they have is asp 3.0. Is there an MVC helper I can use to display these ads on a MVC C# Razor page? I can't find anything about MVC and displaying web ads online at all. Would love some help, I am totally stuck.

If I use regular Adsense Javascript code. The code doesn't load when I click around the site. Only when I click refresh on the page.

Answer (score 0):

A simple HtmlHelper translated from Adsense ASP sample :

```
public static class AdsenseHelper
{
    public static MvcHtmlString Adsense(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string clientKey, string adSlot)
    {
        var context = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext;
        var request = context.Request;

        int googleTime = (DateTime.Now - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).Days;
        var googleDt = (1000 * googleTime) + Math.Round(1000d * (DateTime.Now - DateTime.Today).Milliseconds);

        var googleUserAgent = context.Server.UrlEncode(request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
        var googleScheme = (string.Compare(request.ServerVariables["HTTPS"], "on") == 0) ? "https://" : "http://";

        var googleAdUrl =
            "http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/ads?" +
            "client=" + clientKey + // ca-mb-pub-0000000000000000
            "&dt=" + googleDt +
            "&ip=" + context.Server.UrlEncode(request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]) +
            "&markup=xhtml" +
            "&output=xhtml" +
            "&ref=" + context.Server.UrlEncode(request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"]) +
            "&slotname=" + adSlot + // 0000000000
            "&url=" + context.Server.UrlEncode(googleScheme + request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"] + request.ServerVariables["URL"]) +
            "&useragent=" + googleUserAgent +
            GoogleScreenRes(context.Request) +
            GoogleMuid(context.Request) +
            GoogleViaAndAccept(context, googleUserAgent);

        using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            string result = client.DownloadString(googleAdUrl);
            return new MvcHtmlString(result);
        }
    }

    private static string GoogleColor(string value, int random)
    {
        var colorArray = value.Split(',');
        return colorArray[random % (colorArray.Length)];
    }

    private static string GoogleScreenRes(HttpRequestBase request)
    {
        var screenRes = request.ServerVariables["HTTP_UA_PIXELS"];
        char delimiter = 'x';
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(screenRes))
        {
            screenRes = request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_UP_DEVCAP_SCREENPIXELS"];
            delimiter = ',';
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(screenRes))
        {
            screenRes = request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_JPHONE_DISPLAY"];
            delimiter = '*';
        }

        if (screenRes != null)
        {
            string[] resArray = screenRes.Split(new[] { delimiter }, 2);
            if (resArray.Length == 2)
            {
                return "&u_w=" + resArray[0] + "&u_h=" + resArray[1];
            }
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }

    private static string GoogleMuid(HttpRequestBase request)
    {
        var muid = request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_DCMGUID"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(muid))
        {
            return "&muid=" + muid;
        }
        muid = request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_UP_SUBNO"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(muid))
        {
            return "&muid=" + muid;
        }
        muid = request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_JPHONE_UID"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(muid))
        {
            return "&muid=" + muid;
        }
        muid = request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_EM_UID"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(muid))
        {
            return "&muid=" + muid;
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }

    private static string GoogleViaAndAccept(HttpContextBase context, string googleUserAgent)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(googleUserAgent))
            return string.Empty;

        string googleViaAndAccept = string.Empty;
        var via = context.Server.UrlEncode(context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_VIA"]);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(via))
        {
            googleViaAndAccept = "&via=" + via;
        }
        var accept = context.Server.UrlEncode(context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_ACCEPT"]);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accept))
        {
            googleViaAndAccept = googleViaAndAccept + "&accept=" + accept;
        }

        return googleViaAndAccept;
    }
}
```

This helper does not work with desktop browsers. But can be bypassed by changing the useragent as Opera Mini.

Like Google says :

*AdSense for Mobile Content is only for use on websites designed with older feature phones in mind. As fully web-capable smartphones become more and more common, we recommend that you use AdSense for Content for all of your Content Ads needs.*